# When I tick the use nodes button no nodes appear on my screen

Tags: node-editor

I am currently doing a donut course by The Blender Guru on Youtube and when I tick the box that says use nodes no nodes appear on screen.

Comment: Hello :). You can press the *Home key* to display all added nodes. If there are none, you can always add them manually.

Comment: @JachymMichal I am a bit confused, where is the home key and also how do i add them in maually?

Comment: No problem, I added an answer with a gif. Please add a screenshot of your workspace into the question :).

Answer (score 1):

This can have multiple reasons.

1. You can try *View > View All*, (<kbd>Home</kbd>) to show all present nodes.
2. If there are none, you can also add them manually through *Add > Search*

[image]